# Python regex to compile job titles from text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that is formatted as such, with each column separated by tab space:

```
CAMPUS  NAME    TITLE
AUJV    "Judith"    Research Technician Associate
BRGE    "Aagesen"   ADJUNCT CLINICAL INSTRUCTOR
YJFF    "Matthew"   HOUSE OFFICER IV
```

I want to write a regular expression that finds the characters on the third column ie. after the second tab space, and labels them as "jobtitle." The purpose is to group job titles together so that I can sort them by frequency.

This is what I have so far, and I am sure that I am matching to the wrong characters:

```
jobtitle_re = re.compile(r"[^\t\w\t]+,(?P<jobtitle>\w+)", re.I)
```

The rest of my code goes like this:

```
for line in salary_file.readlines():
  line.rstrip()
  (campus, name, title) = line.split('\t')
  jobtitle = jobtitle_re.match(title).group('jobtitle')

  titlecount[jobtitle] = titlecount.setdedault(jobtitle,0)+1

print "\nMost common job titles\n-------"
i = 0
for title, titlecount in sorted(titlecount.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k), reverse=True):
  i += 1
  print "%d. %s\t%s" % (i,title, titlecount)
```

Comment: Oh my! You don't need a regex.  Split by the tab character instead.

Comment: If it is a tab-delimited, then str.split is a better solution

Comment: I'm sorting the jobtitles by frequency, that's why I need regex to group them together.

Comment: Fix the indentation, please.

Comment: "I'm sorting the jobtitles by frequency, that's why I need regex to group them together" - that doesn't make sense at all. Regex groups are groups of characters within a _single string_, they aren't groups of matches in multiple strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you need a regex either. How about...

```
from collections import Counter

titles = []

for line in salary_file.readlines():
    line.rstrip()
    (campus, name, title) = line.split('\t')
    titles.append(title)

print "\nMost common job titles\n-------"

for i, (title, titlecount) in enumerate(Counter(titles).most_common()):
  print "%d. %s\t%s" % (i, title, titlecount)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand your approach now, it works like wonder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why split wouldn't work for you, but here is a regex as an alternative:

```
^[A-Z]+[ \t]+"\w+"[ \t]+(?P<jobtitle>[\w ]+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mdcFDNl37PEHK_2u)

Note that if it's truly tab-delimined, you can change `[ \t]+` to `\t+`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I get this: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. May I ask where I went wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, so I'm afraid I'm not going to be very helpful. I did double check that the regex is solid according to Debuggex under "Python".

Comment: @user3440320 aliteralmind's regex is trying to pull the campus, name and title out of a whole line from the file. You're already doing that with your `string.split('\t')`, and then applying the regex to just the title text. It won't match anything, so where you call `match(title).group('jobtitle')` the call to match returns None (no match) and then you try to call .group() on that, which throws an AttributeError.

Comment: Thanks for the Debuggex reference, it helps me to visualize the position of the string with my test data.